# how to specify table line width and color of a merged cell

Tags: tables, color, line

how can i use \multicolumn after \noalign{\color{greenTable}\hrule height 1.5pt} ?

i keep getting an error
here is my full code:

```
   \begin{tabular}{
        l
        |
        c
        |
        c
    }
    one & two & three \\
    \noalign{
        \color{green}
        \hrule height 1.5pt
    }%
    \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}& 3\\
    4   & 5   & 6     \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: `\noalign{{
        \color{green}
        \hrule height 1.5pt
    }}%`

Answer (score 0):

[Please always provide a full document, as below]

You need to keep the color restore inside the `\noalign` group:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{
        l
        |
        c
        |
        c
    }
    one & two & three \\
    \noalign{{
        \color{green}
        \hrule height 1.5pt
    }}%
    \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}& 3\\
    4   & 5   & 6     \\
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```